# HAProxy errors in configuration file

Tags: proxy, https, haproxy, access-control-list, parsing

I am trying to configure `Pass through` SSL using HAproxy but I get a lot of errors

here my example

error detected while parsing ACL

```
frontend public_ssl
        mode tcp
        option tcplog
        bind *:443

        tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
        tcp-request content accept if { req.ssl_hello_type 1 }

        acl foo_app_bar req.ssl_sni -i bar.example.com
        acl foo_app_baz req.ssl_sni -i baz.example.com

        use_backend foo_bk_bar if foo_app_bar
        use_backend foo_bk_baz if foo_app_baz

        default_backend foo_bk_default
```

But I am getting following errors

```
[ALERT] 339/143013 (3828) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:45] : error detected in frontend 'public_ssl' while parsing 'if' condition
[ALERT] 339/143013 (3828) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:47] : error detected while parsing ACL 'foo_app_bar'.
[ALERT] 339/143013 (3828) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:48] : error detected while parsing ACL 'foo_app_baz'.
[ALERT] 339/143013 (3828) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:50] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 339/143013 (3828) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:51] : error detected while parsing switching rule.
[ALERT] 339/143013 (3828) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
```

I have tried to use code example from a lot of tutorials and articles even from official site, but each time I get parsing errors.

Comment: you are showing us a frontend that does not match the one with the parsing error (/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:45)

Comment: @JeffW. I have just update my question, sorry for mistake

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for help. The problem was in ancient version of `HAProxy`. Because I've installed it using `apt-get install haproxy`. Version 1.4 2013

I have just compiled the recent version 1.7 from sources and it started fine.

Thanks.